# Is the hadith of music being haram is a misunderstanding?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, hadith-interpretation, music

In Sahih al-Bukhari, 5590

> Narrated Abu 'Amir or Abu Malik Al-Ash'ari:

> that he heard the Prophet saying, "From among my followers there will be some people who will consider illegal sexual intercourse, the wearing of silk, the drinking of alcoholic drinks and the use of musical instruments, as lawful.

Here it clearly says musical instruments are haram. And also the wearing of silk. But it is permissible to wear silk for women in Islam. Because of that, A brother is saying to me, The hadith has been misunderstood that music is haram. He's saying that if music used in good intention than it's halal. How do i answer him?

Comment: Does your friend also argue that zina and wine are halal when done in 'good intention'?

Comment: @UmH what about the silk issue?